# remove elements from a data.frame with lists of lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a data.frame of length 3 - `sku_data`:
A sample of the data is:

```
sku_data <- data.frame(
  sku = c(1200337,1200518,1200586,1200590),
  units_current = I(list(c(1),1:3,1:4,2:4)),
  units_end = I(list(1:3,1,2:4,1:3))
)

#      sku units_current units_end
#1 1200337             1   1, 2, 3
#2 1200518       1, 2, 3         1
#3 1200586    1, 2, 3, 4   2, 3, 4
#4 1200590       2, 3, 4   1, 2, 3
```

I want to remove those elements where the length of `units_current` or `units_end` is `<=1`. They are both lists of lists.

Thanks

Comment: please provide `dput(head(sku_data))`

Comment: Edited to make the example _much_ smaller and simpler. 200 item lists weren't really needed to show the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
f <- function(x) which(sapply(x, length) <= 1L)

sku_data[-unlist(lapply(sku_data[-1], f)), ]
#       sku units_current units_end
# 3 1200586    1, 2, 3, 4   2, 3, 4
# 4 1200590       2, 3, 4   1, 2, 3
```

And testing on more than one/uneven length matches

```
(sku2 <- rbind(sku_data, sku_data, sku_data[1,]))
#       sku units_current units_end
# 1 1200337             1   1, 2, 3
# 2 1200518       1, 2, 3         1
# 3 1200586    1, 2, 3, 4   2, 3, 4
# 4 1200590       2, 3, 4   1, 2, 3
# 5 1200337             1   1, 2, 3
# 6 1200518       1, 2, 3         1
# 7 1200586    1, 2, 3, 4   2, 3, 4
# 8 1200590       2, 3, 4   1, 2, 3
# 9 1200337             1   1, 2, 3
sku2[-unlist(lapply(sku2[-1], f)), ]
#       sku units_current units_end
# 3 1200586    1, 2, 3, 4   2, 3, 4
# 4 1200590       2, 3, 4   1, 2, 3
# 7 1200586    1, 2, 3, 4   2, 3, 4
# 8 1200590       2, 3, 4   1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is:

```
sku_data[!rowSums(`dim<-`(rapply(sku_data[,-1], length) <=1,
                                         dim(sku_data)-c(0,1))),]
#      sku units_current units_end
#3 1200586    1, 2, 3, 4   2, 3, 4
#4 1200590       2, 3, 4   1, 2, 3
```